# Why my css path is not taken use express + ejs

Tags: express, path, ejs

Today,I use express and ejs find a question,help me!

app.js set path

```
app.use('/static',express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

login.ejs css path

```
href='/static/stylesheets/bootstrap.min.css'
```

My file path

```
 -public
 --stylesheets
 ---bootstrap.min.js
```

Open localhost:3000/static/stylesheets/bootstrap.min.css is not find css file!

Answer (score 0):

It should be `app.use(express.static('/public'))` to serve all folders inside `/public`. The urls for those files will then be `/stylesheets/bootstrap.min.css`

Reason: using `app.use(/static',express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')))` serves files starting with `/static/stylesheets/bootstrap.min.css`. But your folder structure does not have `/static`.

Source: http://expressjs.com/starter/static-files.html

Comment: I already modification according your code,but not work still.

Comment: @JasonHou - What are the urls that are getting 404? localhost:3000/stylesheets/bootstrap.min.css

Comment: Don't open page,It's not 404.

Comment: What is not working? Update the question with your full express init code, along with the jade file links and the error message